# PGError: ERROR: column “recipes.id” must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I have this SQL query in my DB which is causing a problem with PostgreSQL on heroku, Causing the page not to load with the above error in the heroku logs. I am using postgreSQL 9.1.6 so previous bugs have apparently been fixed

```
def self.top_countries
joins(:recipes).
  select('countries.*, count(*) AS recipes_count').
  group('countries.id').
  order('recipes_count DESC')
```

end

I am unsure on how to refactor this so that it will work.Could anyone advise please?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def self.top_countries
joins(:recipes).
  select('countries.id, count(*) AS recipes_count').
  group('countries.id').
  order('recipes_count DESC')
```

This generates the SQL

```
select countries.id, count(*) AS recipes_count
  from countries
  join recipes on countries.id = recipes.country_id
 group by countries.id
 order by recipes_count
```

You'll notice that you only have 2 columns in the SELECT.
Not being a Heroku expert, I suspect you can get it to work by explicitly listing all column that you need from countries, and grouping by the full column list i.e.

```
def self.top_countries
joins(:recipes).
  select('countries.id, countries.name, countries.other, count(*) AS recipes_count').
  group('countries.id, countries.name, countries.other').
  order('recipes_count DESC')
```

There might be a more concise way to join the original answer (top part) with another join to `top_countries` on `countries.id` to get the rest of the columns after the `group by`.

Comment: ive accepted answer as that solved that issue but now i get  ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: name):
any ideas? its regarding a .each block

Comment: ah right thank you, i take it countries.other is just naming the rest of the columns i n the model? but want if i only want the name and id?

Comment: "countries.other" is just an example of a column named "other" for illustration

Comment: sorry for another question but i have countries.id, countries.name in select and group, i do have other columns in the model but dont use them, do i have to declare them?

Comment: i guess i could just remove them from the model and leave just id and name in the model?